# Start up & shut down webapp instance in azure - in code

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-worker-roles

How can I start a new Azure webapp instance with code? And then start a webjob in code ...When the webjob is finished I'd like to shut down this webapp instance. What the best way to do this?

Comment: So you only need a web app for the web job? if so, then go for the scheduled Job directly

Answer (score 0):

> And then start a webjob in code

We can use rest API to start a webjob. Please have a look at [this article](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#stop-a-continuous-job). It contains start/stop/delete a continues job.

> How can I start a new Azure webapp instance with code?

If you want to start a new Azure Web app, please try Management Library. There is a RestartAsync method in it. Please have a look at [this article](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/master/ManagementLibrarySample/Program.cs) to get started. If you want to shut down the app instance, Please try to change Azure web app's web hosting plan via Management library. As I know, It is difficult to shut down the special instance directly.